# Getting error while installing NPM modules in CPanel?

Tags: node.js, cpanel, package.json, shared-hosting

I get an error after installing **Node** in **CPanel**, I uploaded my **package.json** file but whenever I tap the **Run NPM install** button, it shows an error on the right hand side saying, Web Application is inaccessible by its address http://www.exampleforquestion.com, the operation was not performed.

Answer (score 23):

You need to stop the application before running `npm install`.